# Subject line include important

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a field 'Priority (dropdown with option 1,2,3)'. When user add new item to list and select 'priority' as 1 , subject line auto include keyword "important".
 I have created workflow in SPD 2010 and used 'send an email' action. By default subject line is "Ticket has been created".

When a user selects priority as 1, the subject line should include "Important-Ticket has been created" and if a user selects 2 or 3 then subject line need to be just "Ticket has been created".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workflows are triggered after item has been created. So in the workflow you can fetch the value of the 'Priority' field and check its value. Your logic should be something like this

```
If(priority == 1)
// send mail with subject "Important-Ticket has been created" 
else
// send mail with subject "Ticket has been created"
```